# Formatting 3 integers (hours, mins, secs) to `00:00:00`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, formatting

I have this at the moment, wondering if there's a cleaner way to do it or if this is already as compact as it gets.

```
 h = "%s" % str(h) if h >= 10 else "0%s" % str(h)
 m = "%s" % str(m) if m >= 10 else "0%s" % str(m)
 s = "%s" % str(s) if s >= 10 else "0%s" % str(s)
 print("{}:{}:{}".format(h, m, s))
```

Comment: [Nicest way to pad zeroes to string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/339007/953482) may be of interest to you. But you might also consider using the `datetime.time` class, which has some [nice string conversion options](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.strftime).

Comment: I'm actually using datetime to get these times, didn't occur to me it would have way to convert them into strings. Thanks!

Comment: You mention you are using datetime to get these times, but how exactly? Python's [datetime has quite a lot of format codes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) such as `%M` for _Minute as a zero-padded decimal number_.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `%` formatting operator already supports 0-padding, just specify the width as `02`. Also, you can pass a tuple to combine multiple numbers into the same string with a single format: `"%02d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s)`.

In Python 3 the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) string method is slightly preferred to the `%` operator, with Python 3.6 further allowing the format string to reference the variables directly. Using such *formatted string literals* or [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), the formatting would be expressed as: `f"{h:02}:{m:02}:{s:02}"`.

As pointed out in the comments, if you're starting with `datetime` objects to begin with, you can use their own [formatting functionality](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.strftime) instead.

Answer (score 20):

Using `format` method. Works in all current Python versions.

```
'{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(h, m, s)
```

See more about string formatting [here](https://pyformat.info/).

Answer (score 7):

To summarize the other answers, here are the different ways to solve the problem.

### From [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) or [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects) object:

```
t = datetime.time(23, 59, 10)  # Example
```

- Call the [`strftime()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) on the object:

  ```
  print( t.strftime("%H:%M:%S") )
  ```
- Use the [str.format() method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

  ```
  print( "{:%H:%M:%S}".format(t) )
  ```

(You can also choose 12-hour notation for the hour; see the documentation.)

### From 3 individual integers:

```
h = 23  # Example
m = 59  # Example
s = 10  # Example
```

- Very manual formatting:

  ```
  h = ("0" if h < 10 else "") + str(h)
  m = ("0" if m < 10 else "") + str(m)
  s = ("0" if s < 10 else "") + str(s)
  print( h + ":" + m + ":" + s )
  ```
- Manual formatting with [`str.zfill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

  ```
  h = str(h).zfill(2)
  m = str(m).zfill(2)
  s = str(s).zfill(2)
  print( h + ":" + m + ":" + s )
  ```
- Use the [`%` formatting operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

  ```
  print( "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s) )
  ```
- Use the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

  ```
  print( "{:02}:{:02}:{:02}".format(h, m, s) )
  ```
- Use [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (Python 3.6+):

  ```
  print( f"{h:02}:{m:02}:{s:02}" )
  ```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments above, using the `datetime` module provides all of this functionality:

```
from datetime import time
h = 21
m = 6
s = 32
output_string = time(h, m, s).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Hit http://strftime.org/ if you're looking for the complete list of supported string formats.